# Multiple Requests at Config Server after Restart

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

After a `POST` to restart on the cloud config client, a new `ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator` is created and the old ones are kept. The problem is, they are all invoked after restart, so if I `POST` to restart 10 times, I get 11 beans *and* 11 invocations, which results in 11 `GET` calls to the config server.

Breakpoint at `SpringApplication#addInitializers(ApplicationContextInitializer<?>... initializers)`

```
this = {SpringApplication@2244} 
initializers = {ApplicationContextInitializer[2]@6093} 
 0 = {PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$56dce074@6097} 
 1 = {EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer@6098} 
this.initializers = {ArrayList@3671}  size = 10
 0 = {DelegatingApplicationContextInitializer@3784} 
 1 = {ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer@3785} 
 2 = {ConfigurationWarningsApplicationContextInitializer@3786} 
 3 = {ServerPortInfoApplicationContextInitializer@3787} 
 4 = {SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer@3788} 
 5 = {AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer@3789} 
 6 = {BootstrapApplicationListener$AncestorInitializer@3678} 
 7 = {PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$56dce074@3705} 
 8 = {EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer@3706} 
 9 = {BootstrapApplicationListener$DelegatingEnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer@3715}
```

As you can see, it is about to add another instance of `PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration` to the `initializer` list.

What could be causing this and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue - there's a bug logged for it on GitHub at: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/138 - there's a project created to reproduce the issue (https://github.com/nicolaferraro/spring-cloud-context-example) and it seems to be something that is fairly common.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I was going crazy